# State of dynamic radio buttons changing on scrolling in a listview Android

Tags: android, listview

We are working on a project where there is a custom listview with a radio group in each list item . The radio buttons in it are generated dynamically.The issue is that on scrolling the state of the selected radio buttons becomes deselected.The following is the code which we have tried:

The adapter getView() method:

```
     @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                option_list = question_list_array.get(position).option_list;
                number_of_options = option_list.size();

                    v_single=convertView;
                    if (v_single == null)
                    {
                        v_single = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_choice_layout, null);
                        sh = new SingleHolder();
                        sh.single_question_name = (TextView) v_single.findViewById(R.id.single_question_name);
                        sh.single_radiogroup = (RadioGroup) v_single.findViewById(R.id.single_radiogroup);
                        v_single.setTag(sh);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sh = (SingleHolder) v_single.getTag();
                    }
                    sh.single_radiogroup.clearCheck();
                    sh.single_radiogroup.removeAllViews();
                    sh.single_question_name.setText(question_list_array.get(position).getQuestion_name());
                    for (int j = 0; j < number_of_options; j++)
                     {
                         RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(context);
                         rb.setId(Integer.parseInt(option_list.get(j).getOption_id()));
                         rb.setText(option_list.get(j).getOption_name());
                         sh.single_radiogroup.addView(rb);
                     }
                   sh.single_radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                            for (int n = 0; n < group.getChildCount(); n++)
                            {
                                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(n);
                                if (Integer.parseInt(option_list.get(n).getOption_id())== checkedId)
                                {
                                    k++;
                                    String result = rb.getText().toString();
                                    sr=new SingleResult();
                                    sr.setAns(result);
                                    sr.setQuestion_id(question_list_array.get(k).getQuestion_id());
                                    single_result.add(sr);
                                    Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    v_final=v_single;

     return v_final;          
    }
private   class SingleHolder
    {
        TextView single_question_name;
        RadioGroup single_radiogroup;


    }
```

EDIT:
this is the single_choice_layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/single_question_name"
      />
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/single_radiogroup"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       >

    </RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi. Our issue is not changing of position of the Radio Button.Our issue is the changing of the selected state of the radio button on scrolling.

Comment: it is same because we are using radio button in whole listview

Comment: probably need your layout file as well

Comment: @IbtehazShawon. i have added the layout file in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //give the corrct class name
    QuestionObj rowObject = question_list_array.get(position);

    option_list = question_list_array.get(position).option_list;
    number_of_options = option_list.size();

    v_single = convertView;
    SingleHolder sh;
    if (v_single == null) {
        v_single = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_choice_layout, null);
        sh = new SingleHolder();
        sh.single_question_name = (TextView) v_single.findViewById(R.id.single_question_name);
        sh.single_radiogroup = (RadioGroup) v_single.findViewById(R.id.single_radiogroup);
        v_single.setTag(sh);
    } else {
        sh = (SingleHolder) v_single.getTag();
    }

    sh.single_question_name.setText(rowObject.getQuestion_name());
    sh.single_radiogroup.clearCheck();
    sh.single_radiogroup.removeAllViews();

    for (int j = 0; j < number_of_options; j++) {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(context);
        rb.setId(Integer.parseInt(option_list.get(j).getOption_id()));
        rb.setText(option_list.get(j).getOption_name());
        sh.single_radiogroup.addView(rb);
    }

    if (rowObject.getSelectedId() != 0) {

        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) sh.single_radiogroup.findViewById(rowObject.getSelectedId());
        if (radioButton != null)
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
    }
    sh.single_radiogroup.setTag(rowObject);
    sh.single_radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            QuestionObj rowObject = (QuestionObj) group.getTag();
            rowObject.setSelectedId(checkedId);
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            rowObject.setAnswer(radioButton.getText());


        }
    });
    v_final = v_single;

    return v_final;
}

private class SingleHolder {
    TextView single_question_name;
    RadioGroup single_radiogroup;
}

class QuestionObj {
    private int selectedId;

    public int getSelectedId() {
        return selectedId;
    }

    public void setSelectedId(int selectedId) {
        this.selectedId = selectedId;
    }
    //put this is in those
    //other fieldds like questionname, question id,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding your code correctly. You need to implement this method as well.

check(int id)
Sets the selection to the radio button whose identifier is passed in parameter.